# Python Pylenium package installation failure: "AttributeError: 'Scheme' object has no attribute 'conftest.py'"

Tags: python, package, attributeerror

Trying to install package with following command and got an error

> pip install pyleniumio

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\mi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\mi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 407, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "c:\users\mi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 71, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\mi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 811, in install
    direct_url=direct_url,
  File "c:\users\mi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 630, in install_wheel
    direct_url=direct_url,
  File "c:\users\mi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 452, in install_unpacked_whee
l
    dest = getattr(scheme, subdir)
AttributeError: 'Scheme' object has no attribute 'conftest.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some python packages require other ways, for example, the POT package requires a specific C++ compiler to install. Make sure you read the entire instructions and have everything you need. Another thing that works for me if you have all the requirements and you are running Linux like me, you can just simply lead your terminal to where the file is and just run for example `python package.py` and it installs. Hopefully, this helped you and you can install your package.